# Sending mailings (newsletters etc.) from a subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain, spf

Our domain has too many (more than 10) spf lookups. This is a problem for some third party programs that use spf records to send out mailings on our behalf. That's why I want to move our marketing mailing to a subdomain. We use Office 365 on our main domain.

We don't send the marketing mailing ourselves, but this is done by a third party that we have added in the spf-record. Can I just add a TXT-record in our domain specifying spf records for a new subdomain or do I also need to add other kind of records?

More specifically: I want our marketing partner to be able to mail from a subdomain. For example info@mail.domain.com. They now use our main domain (which is not best practice, i know). They use mailchimp to send out mailings for us. I want to know if it's enough to just add a TXT-record with spf on a new subdomain to make them able to send mails from that domainname. To be able to reply to that e-mail subdomain isn't necessary

Comment: You should more explicit

Comment: I want our marketing partner to be able to mail from a subdomain. For example info@mail.domain.com. They now use our main domain (which is not best practice, i know). They use mailchimp to send out mailings for us. I want to know if it's enough to just add a TXT-record with spf on a new subdomain to make them able to send mails from that domainname. To be able to reply to that e-mail subdomain isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

First, I would ask your marketing partner for the records they need to make it work instead of making assumptions up front.
My company asks our clients to add both CNAME and TXT records to enable domain verification, DKIM and spf.